How can I make sure that these fields align using only Grid, Border, and Flow layout managers? JAVA SWING GUI Development
I would like to align these fields without having to resort to setPreferredSize. I am a student. This is my goal for it to copy. This is for a homework and I have been trying to get this to align for days already but I just cannot get it right. We are only allowed to use Grid, Flow, or Border Layout Managers.
package Main;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class SatelliteManagementSystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the main frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpaceX Starlink Project");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(550, 400);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Load the image icon for the application
        ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon("icon.png");  // Replace with the path to your icon image
        Image img = imgIcon.getImage();
        frame.setIconImage(img);  // Set the icon for the frame

        
// Main Panel for the form, with BorderLayout
        JPanel formPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

        // Left Panel for labels (WEST in BorderLayout)
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1, 10, 10));
        labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Satellite ID:", SwingConstants.LEFT));
        labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Satellite Name:", SwingConstants.LEFT));
        labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Longitude:", SwingConstants.LEFT));
        labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Elevation:", SwingConstants.LEFT));

        // Right Panel for text fields and buttons (CENTER in BorderLayout)
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1, 10, 10));

        // Satellite ID field and Find Satellite button
        JPanel satelliteIDFieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 0));  // 1 row, 2 columns
        JTextField satelliteIDField = new JTextField();
        JButton findSatelliteButton = new JButton("Find Satellite");
        satelliteIDFieldPanel.add(satelliteIDField);  // Add Satellite ID field to the first column
        satelliteIDFieldPanel.add(findSatelliteButton);  // Add Find Satellite button to the second column

        // Satellite Name field
        JPanel satelliteNameFieldPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 0));
        JTextField satelliteNameField = new JTextField();
        satelliteNameFieldPanel.add(satelliteNameField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Longitude and Latitude fields in one row (Longitude field is longer)
        JPanel latLongPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 0));  // 1 row, 2 columns
        JTextField longitudeField = new JTextField();
        latLongPanel.add(longitudeField);  // Longitude field in the first column

        // Panel to hold latitude label and text field in BorderLayout (Aligning similarly to longitude)
        JPanel latPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 0));  // Use BorderLayout here
        JLabel latitudeLabel = new JLabel("Latitude:", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        JTextField latitudeField = new JTextField();
        latPanel.add(latitudeLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);  // Latitude label aligned to the left
        latPanel.add(latitudeField, BorderLayout.CENTER);  // Latitude field fills the remaining space
        latLongPanel.add(latPanel);  // Add latPanel to the second column of latLongPanel

        // grid for elev and health to easily organize arrangements
        JPanel elevHealthPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 0));  // 1 row, 2 columns
        JTextField elevationField = new JTextField();
        elevHealthPanel.add(elevationField);  // Elevation field in the first column

        // Panel for elev and health combo box (border)
        JPanel healthPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));  
        JLabel healthStatusLabel = new JLabel("Health Status:", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        JComboBox<String> healthStatusCombo = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{});
        healthPanel.add(healthStatusLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);  
        healthPanel.add(healthStatusCombo, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
        elevHealthPanel.add(healthPanel); 


        // Add input fields to input panel
        inputPanel.add(satelliteIDFieldPanel);
        inputPanel.add(satelliteNameFieldPanel);
        inputPanel.add(latLongPanel);
        inputPanel.add(elevHealthPanel);

        // Add label panel and input panel to formpanel
        formPanel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        formPanel.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        // Panel for the buttons type shit
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3, 15, 0));  
        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
        JButton updateButton = new JButton("Update");
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        buttonPanel.add(saveButton);
        buttonPanel.add(updateButton);
        buttonPanel.add(deleteButton);

        // Wrap buttonPanel with a margin
        JPanel buttonWrapperPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        buttonWrapperPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0));  // Adds 10px margin at the top and bottom
        buttonWrapperPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Text area panel
        JPanel textAreaPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
        textAreaPanel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        // Panel for Clear All button (below the text area)
        JPanel clearPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 10));
        JButton clearAllButton = new JButton("Clear All");
        clearPanel.add(clearAllButton);

        // Combine the buttons and text area into a single panel using BorderLayout
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        centerPanel.add(buttonWrapperPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);  // Buttons on top of the text area
        centerPanel.add(textAreaPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);  // Text area in the center
        centerPanel.add(clearPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);  // Clear All button below the text area

        // Create a panel to wrap the entire content with margins (using EmptyBorder)
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)); // Adds a margin of 20px on all sides
        contentPanel.add(formPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Add the contentPanel to the main frame
        frame.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);  // Add the content panel to the frame

        // Set visibility
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


Expected output:

My output:
updated output

why "only Grid, Border, and Flow layout managers"?  A GridBagLayout would be helpful

What is the actual problem? Is there any difference with the output vs expected? This is a starting point to learn a GridBagLayout.

It's because our facilitator restricts us to only using those three layout managers to identically copy her output. However, I can't get it to work by only using those three outputs. I have to use setpref if i really want to copy it :( so i am asking here for help.

..to identically copy her output. - well, a picture is NOT a requirement. If that is all the facilitator gave you, the problem is impossible to solve. I can see a relationship between the 4 labels on the left. However, there is no relationship between the text field and the button on the first row. Similarly, there appears to be no relationship between the components on the 3rd and 4th row. There is also no relationship between the buttons on the 5th row. However, hard coding preferred sizes is also not a solution. What happens if the user resizes the frame? We need proper requirements.

Okay I just updated the post and put in my new code.  Is it possible for me to just put the health and latitude in one grid for them to align?

I could understand if this were a code challenge, but as an assignment, it’s just awful.  No one will ever be forced to avoid the use of GridBagLayout in the real world, so this isn’t a useful learning experience.  In fact, teaching someone how to use GridBagLayout is probably ten times more valuable than teaching them how to get creative with other layouts.
But we can’t do anything to change this awful assignment, so… I would make use of multiple GridLayouts for everything except the JTextArea and the clear button.  It’s the only way to guarantee alignment of the various fields.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SatelliteManagementSystem {
    static void showWindow() {
        JLabel satelliteIDLabel = new JLabel("Satellite ID:");
        JLabel satelliteNameLabel = new JLabel("Satellite Name:");
        JLabel longitudeLabel = new JLabel("Longitude:");
        JLabel elevationLabel = new JLabel("Elevation:");

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 6));
        leftPanel.add(satelliteIDLabel);
        leftPanel.add(satelliteNameLabel);
        leftPanel.add(longitudeLabel);
        leftPanel.add(elevationLabel);

        JTextField satelliteIDField = new JTextField();  // Text field resizes
        JButton findSatelliteButton = new JButton("Find Satellite");

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 12, 0));
        topPanel.add(satelliteIDField);
        topPanel.add(findSatelliteButton);

        JTextField satelliteNameField = new JTextField();

        JPanel upperFieldsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 6));
        upperFieldsPanel.add(topPanel);
        upperFieldsPanel.add(satelliteNameField);

        JTextField longitudeField = new JTextField();
        JLabel latitudeLabel = new JLabel("Latitude:");
        JTextField latitudeField = new JTextField();
        JTextField elevationField = new JTextField();
        JLabel healthStatusLabel = new JLabel("Health Status:");
        JComboBox<String> healthStatusCombo =
            new JComboBox<>(new String[] { "Healthy", "Unhealthy" });

        JPanel lowerFieldsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 3, 12, 6));
        lowerFieldsPanel.add(longitudeField);
        lowerFieldsPanel.add(latitudeLabel);
        lowerFieldsPanel.add(latitudeField);
        lowerFieldsPanel.add(elevationField);
        lowerFieldsPanel.add(healthStatusLabel);
        lowerFieldsPanel.add(healthStatusCombo);

        JPanel fieldsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 6));
        fieldsPanel.add(upperFieldsPanel);
        fieldsPanel.add(lowerFieldsPanel);
        fieldsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 6, 0, 0));

        // Panel for Save, Update, Delete buttons (above the text area)
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3, 15, 0));  // 1 row, 3 columns with 15px gap
        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
        JButton updateButton = new JButton("Update");
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        buttonPanel.add(saveButton);
        buttonPanel.add(updateButton);
        buttonPanel.add(deleteButton);

        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(12, 0, 12, 0));

        JPanel formPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        formPanel.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        formPanel.add(fieldsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        formPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        formPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 0, 6));

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        JPanel textAreaPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        textAreaPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textAreaPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 6, 0, 6));

        JPanel clearPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 10));
        JButton clearAllButton = new JButton("Clear All");
        clearPanel.add(clearAllButton);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpaceX Starlink Project");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon("icon.png");  // Replace with the path to your icon image
        Image img = imgIcon.getImage();
        frame.setIconImage(img);  // Set the icon for the frame

        frame.add(formPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(textAreaPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(clearPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> showWindow());
    }
}


Hey, that's pretty good. Thanks for the help! I also have come with up with something similar to that earlier . However, I am wondering if it's possible for the health and the latitude panels to be in the same grid to ensure their alignment? Putting them in separate grids still align them yes, but upon resizing, the gap between the field and their respective label will get out of hand. I was wondering if it's possible to nest border and grid.

They’re already in the same GridLayout.  If you’re asking how to allow the JTextFields to expand while the labels do not, during a resize of the window, there is no way to do that.  That is one of the things GridBagLayout was designed to do.
